# In the 2004 film version of The Stepford Wives, were the wives turned to robots?

Tags: the-stepford-wives

In the newer version of the Stepford Wives (2004), it shows some of the "turned" wives doing humanly impossible things like placing a hand on a burning stove, spinning at high velocity, or despensing money like an ATM.

But the ending of the movie shows that

> the wives were simply being implanted with chips down their spine; when the control room was destroyed, all the wives simply went back to being their normal selves.

Were some of them robots and some not? Were they gutted and filled with machine parts?

Comment: http://www.stepfordwives.org/diary/stepfordwife-com-guide-to-the-stepford-movies/the-stepford-wives-organization-reviews-the-stepford-wives-2004-movie-version/

Comment: In the book, they're robots, although it's never really *shown*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I remember thinking the exact same thing when watching the film. I managed to explain it away to myself as such: the idea of the film was terrible.

The original idea was that they were robot copies of their wives. But that begs the question, did they kill their wives or hold them prisoner somewhere? Were they having sex with robots the whole time?

I imagine they changed the ending of the movie to include the chip element after large portions of the film were complete and didn't have the time/money to replace the robot elements with something that made more sense.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that they changed the ending because it was considered far too dark. I think this was probably done either mid-stream, or possibly after screening the movie to test audiences, which would explain why the ending doesn't fit well with other scenes.

Comment: According to this review; http://www.stepfordwives.org/diary/stepfordwife-com-guide-to-the-stepford-movies/the-stepford-wives-organization-reviews-the-stepford-wives-2004-movie-version/, the DVD commentary explained that it was indeed down to studio interference and the fact that the focus groups didn't like the ending..

Answer (score 1):

I saw a work print of the original cut and it was a far better film. The women were robots but retained their original brains. At the end of the film, they did regain their human consciousness, but was forced to stay in Stepford because they were machines.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for the version that the original asker is wondering about?